# Pine Script: How to remove "syntax error at input 'crossed' "

Tags: pine-script

i am unable to remove the syntax error at input. it is showing for below coding. Can someone check and send me back the running script without any syntax. it is for pine script in trading view.
thanks for the help.
The code is as below and the problem is occurring at : "if crossed" line, showing syntax error.

```
//@version=4

par1=input(21)
par2=input(55)
ema1=ema(close,par1)
ema2=ema(close,par2)
buy=ema1>ema2
sell=ema2>ema1
mycolor= iff(buy,color.green,iff(sell,color.blue,color.red))
barcolor(color=mycolor)

ema100=ema(close,100)
ibuy=crossover(ema1,ema2)
iSell=crossunder(ema1,ema2)
//iSell=crossunder(close,ema1)
Varp=tostring(close[1])
crossed =crossover(ema(close,par1),ema(close,par2))

if crossed
   I = label.new(bar_index,na,tostring(close))
       color=color.green,
       textcolor=color.white,
       style=label.style_labelup,yloc=yloc.belowbar)
crossed2 =crossunder(ema(close,par1),ema(close,par2))
if crossed2
   I = label.new(bar_index.na,tostring(close))
       color=color.red,
       textcolor=color.white,
       style=label.style_labeldown,yloc=yloc.abovebar)

plot(ema(close,par1),"EMA Short",color=color.blue)
plot(ema(close,par2),"EMA Long",color=color.orange)

longCondition = crossover(ema(close,par1),ema(close,par2))
if (longCondition)
strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id",strategy.long)

shortCondition = crossunder(ema(close,par1),ema(close,par2))
if (shortCondition)
strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id",strategy.short)
```

Answer (score 0):

When programming, every character counts. You had 3 spaces here instead of 4:

```
    I = label.new(bar_index,na,tostring(close),
```

and under `if crossed2` you had this:

```
   I = label.new(bar_index.na,tostring(close))
```

instead of this:

```
    I = label.new(bar_index,na,tostring(close),
```

There are only two characters changed but the code will not compile without them.

You were also missing a `strategy()` declaration statement at the beginning of your script. See the [usrman on structuring scripts](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Structure_of_the_script.html) and on [continuing lines](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Line_wrapping.html).
Complete code:

```
//@version=4
strategy("S")

par1=input(21)
par2=input(55)
ema1=ema(close,par1)
ema2=ema(close,par2)
buy=ema1>ema2
sell=ema2>ema1
mycolor= iff(buy,color.green,iff(sell,color.blue,color.red))
barcolor(color=mycolor)

ema100=ema(close,100)
ibuy=crossover(ema1,ema2)
iSell=crossunder(ema1,ema2)
//iSell=crossunder(close,ema1)
Varp=tostring(close[1])
crossed = crossover(ema(close,par1),ema(close,par2))

if crossed
    I = label.new(bar_index,na,tostring(close),
      color=color.green,
      textcolor=color.white,
      style=label.style_labelup,yloc=yloc.belowbar)
crossed2 =crossunder(ema(close,par1),ema(close,par2))
if crossed2
    I = label.new(bar_index,na,tostring(close),
      color=color.red,
      textcolor=color.white,
      style=label.style_labeldown,yloc=yloc.abovebar)

plot(ema(close,par1),"EMA Short",color=color.blue)
plot(ema(close,par2),"EMA Long",color=color.orange)

longCondition = crossover(ema(close,par1),ema(close,par2))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id",strategy.long)

shortCondition = crossunder(ema(close,par1),ema(close,par2))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id",strategy.short)
```